# R call function with and without an argument

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing, stdin

There's a function I want to call recursively in R. The first time, I don't pass any argument to it, and `readLines` does the job. So it would be something like this:

```
func<-function(word){
  if(word doesn't exist){
    word<-readLines(stdin(),n=1)
  }
  ... #function transform word into next_word
  func(next_word)
}

func()
```

I wonder if that's possible.

Comment: Give the function formal `word` a default value perhaps? `func <- function(word = NA)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to set the default of `word` to `NULL`:

```
func<-function(word = NULL){
  if(is.null(word)){
    word<-readLines(stdin(),n=1)
  }
  #stuff
}
```

Then, when you call `func` and provide an argument, it will be used as the object indicated by the symbol `word`. If you call it without an argument, `word` will be the default, `NULL`, and thus information will be read from `stdin`.